# Excel : inserting columns with formula, automatically

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I am not good with excel but have got this task. There are columns corresponding to months say from January to May after which there are columns with same months which should have the cumulative sum up to the month corresponding to the first set of columns. 
So, if a column (say June) is inserted after the column of May in the first set, I should automatically have a cumulative sum column (I should not have to insert it separately) corresponding to June with desired formula in the second set of columns.

Am I required to use macros, of which I have got NO IDEA.

Comment: How flexible is the schema? Could you have each month on a row instead? If so, you could produce your desired output without code using a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon.

I believe you can do this with one formula that's a combination of locked and unlocked references like this:

```
    =SUM($A2:A2)
```

Assuming your January column is in column A, this formula would sum only January. Then, when you copied the formula over a column, it would change to Sum($A2:B2), thus adding in February. So all you would have to do is either:
A. Insert your columns, then copy this formula over from the previous month's column
B. Copy the previous month's column over and rename the month

Have a nice day! -Matt

Comment: Hi Mat,
my requirement is that I shouldn't have to copy the formula or cells. I am sorry if it was not clear from the description earlier. I have updated it.
Thanks for the attempt.